# Interesting import behavior in ipython

Tags: python, ipython, python-import, graph-tool

I noticed this while playing around with graph_tool. Some module attributes only seem to be available when run from ipython. The simplest example (example.py)

```
import graph_tool as gt

g = gt.Graph()
gt.draw.sfdp_layout(g)
```

Runs without error from ipython using `run example.y', but from the command line,`python example.py` yields

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'draw'
```

The same hold true for `ipython example.py`. I'm lost as to what would cause this. I would like to access the draw module but it seems like I can only do this via `from graph_tool.draw import *` Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import all modules you are using explicitly. In your case you need to add e.g. `import graph_tool.draw as gt_draw` (just adding `import graph_tool.draw` may be enough but this code may be considered not obvious).

Answer (score 1):

While importing graph-tool, import it as:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt
```

This imports all modules from graph-tool and if all necessary things are installed, this should work for you.